# substring date from 2 dates object

Tags: python, pandas, date

I use pandas to store a list of excel files to variable excel_list

Then I tried to get the "date" from excel sheet.
This is my code:

```
xls_list = []
for file in xls_list:
    excel_list.append(pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=None))

closed_between = excel_list[0]['Report Info'][excel_list[0]['Report Info'].columns[1]][(excel_list[0]['Report Info'].loc[excel_list[0]['Report Info']['Title']=='Closed Between'].index)]
```

I can get the value out like below:

> 3    03/01/2022 12:00 AM - 03/01/2022 11:59 PM
> Name: Chat Summary By Hour, Folder, Date, dtype: object

However, when I tried to slice or strip the date out. I was not able to do it.
This code shows error:

```
dt.strptime(closed_between , '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Result:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 dt.strptime(match , '%m/%d/%Y')
>
> AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'

this code shows no change:

```
match[0:11]
```

Result:

> 3    03/01/2022 12:00 AM - 03/01/2022 11:59 PM
> Name: Chat Summary By Hour, Folder, Date, dtype: object

My goal is to substring the first date in the string. Please help improving my knowledge, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AttributeError**

You probably imported datetime like `import datetime as dt`. This causes `AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'`.

It should be `from datetime import datetime as dt`. Then you can use `dt.strptime`.

---

**TypeError**

Presumably your closed_between is a Series, not a str. It says so quite explicitly in the error: `...must be str, not Series.`. If you know that you get only one value back, you can use dt.strptime(closed_between[0], '%m/%d/%Y')

---

**Other issue**

You can't just apply strptime with format `"%m/%d/%Y"` to the string `"03/01/2022 12:00 AM - 03/01/2022 11:59 PM"`, as this format does not match the string at all. You first have to split the string, e.g. `closed_between[0].split(" ")[0]` giving `03/01/2022` and then you can send it through strptime.

Comment: hi mcsoini, you're right, and I fixed as you suggest. it still shows the error as below: **---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-146-ec57fa20c367> in <module>
----> 1 dt.strptime(match , '%m/%d/%Y')

TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series**

Comment: @MarkYu see updated answer